# Two people cant type simultaneously in a simple collaborative document

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io

Here is my code

server.js

```
var http = require('http');
var app = require('express')();
var server = http.createServer(app).listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

var textData = "some random initial text that will be changed forever, never to be restored to its original state."

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

var users = 0;

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    users++;
    console.log(users + " users are here.");


    //broadcast recieved data

    socket.on('textChange', function(text){
        textData = text;
        socket.broadcast.emit('updatedText', textData);
    });



    socket.on("disconnect", function(){
        users--;
        console.log(users + " users are here.");
    })

});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
    /* global io */
        var socket = io();
        $(document).ready(function() {


            //send value on key up

            $('#textarea').keyup(function(){
               socket.emit('textChange', $('#textarea').val());
            });

            //recieve changed value

            socket.on('updatedText', function(text){
                $('#textarea').val(text);
            });

        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        form, form * {
            width: 100%;
            height: 400px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <h1>HELLO</h1>  
    <h2></h2>
    <form action="">
        <textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
    </form>  
</body>

</html>
```

It is working as inteded but when the two people type simultaniously, it alternates between them and just bugs out. How can I make it so that two people can type together.
I am thinking about using diff-patch but Im not sure if it will even solve this issue.
Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can add some user identifier(e.g. sessionid or uuid or other stuff) to recognize the users,etc:

```
// add user id
var user = Math.random();

$('#textarea').keyup(function(){
    socket.emit('textChange', {name: user, val: $('#textarea').val()});
});

//recieve changed value
socket.on('updatedText', function(text){
    if (text.user == user) {
        $('#textarea').val(text.val);
    }
});
```